# jQuery UI Slider background

Tags: jquery, user-interface, background, slider, range

I have a range slider and I have an image for the selected part of the slider.
[image: range slider]

The problem is that when I move the left slider, the background image moves too. I would like the background image stay fixed. The only way I can think of doing this is to calculate how many pixels the slider was moved and subtract that from the x position of the background image. Is there any other easier way to do this.

```
.ui-widget-header{ //selected part of the bar
        background: url('../images/elements/sliderBarSelected.png');
```

That's the code to change the background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to do it with css. Because the ui-widget-header's width is set dynamically you need to dynamically change background-position of the background-image with 'slide' callback.

Also you can try using:

```
background: url('../images/elements/sliderBarSelected.png') 50% 50%;
```

so the effect will be the same for both sliders.

Answer (score -1):

try using
`background-attachment: fixed`